# Zero pad array based on other array's shape

Tags: python, numpy, zero-padding

I've got K feature vectors that all share dimension n but have a variable dimension m (n x m). They all live in a list together.

```
to_be_padded = []

to_be_padded.append(np.reshape(np.arange(9),(3,3)))

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

to_be_padded.append(np.reshape(np.arange(18),(3,6)))

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])

to_be_padded.append(np.reshape(np.arange(15),(3,5)))

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

What I am looking for is a smart way to zero pad the rows of these np.arrays such that they all share the same dimension m. I've tried solving it with np.pad but I have not been able to come up with a pretty solution. Any help or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

The result should leave the arrays looking like this:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0]])

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 0],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 0],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0]])
```

Comment: Do you want to leave the padded arrays separate, or joined in a bigger array?

Comment: joined in a bigger array, which is just done by np.concatenate(padded_features). The chosen answer works like a charm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) for that, which can also pad `2-D` arrays using a tuple of values specifying the padding width, `((top, bottom), (left, right))`. For that you could define:

```
def pad_to_length(x, m):
    return np.pad(x,((0, 0), (0, m - x.shape[1])), mode = 'constant')
```

**Usage**

You could start by finding the `ndarray` with the highest amount of columns. Say you have two of them, `a` and `b`:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

b = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

m = max(i.shape[1] for i in [a,b])
# 5
```

And then use this parameter to pad the `ndarrays`:

```
pad_to_length(a, m)
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: padded_features = [pad_to_length(x, m) for x in features] works perfectly!

Comment: I am getting an `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]` for this (specifically the `pad_to_length` function). Would you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no very efficient solution for this. I think you will need to loop over the list with a for loop and treat every array individually:

```
for i in range(len(to_be_padded)):
    padded = np.zeros((n, maxM))
    padded[:,:to_be_padded[i].shape[1]] = to_be_padded[i]
    to_be_padded[i] = padded
```

where `maxM` is the longest `m` of the matrices in your list.