# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,2) and requested shape (3,2)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a bunch of (greyscale) images of different sizes that I resize to ensure one dimension is the same and pad the other dimension ([a la this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591202/13112739)). Yet, I get the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,2) and requested shape (3,2)` on the 4th line (second to last line) of the code below. How would I solve this?

I tried running on non-greyscale images ([as suggested here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1435#issuecomment-482953102)), yet this still doesn't work.

My code:

```
image = cv2.imread(filepath)
width = int((height / image.shape[1]) * image.shape[0])
image = cv2.resize(image, (width, height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
image = np.pad(image,((0,0), (0,1028 - image.shape[1])), mode = 'constant')
data.append(image)
```

Comment: The images may be grayscale on the disk, but since you're using `imread` with the second argument unspecified, they're loaded as BGR. That means the numpy array that holds it has 3 axes, yet in `np.pad` you only specify 2 tuples.

Comment: @DanMašek How would I change it to add 0s everywhere there is no data currently?

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work unless you are loading RGB images.
So make sure that the images are in Grayscale mode

You can load an image in grayscale mode:

```
image = cv2.imread('./image.tif',0)
```

Or simply convert it:

```
image = cv2.imread('./image.tif')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Otherwise, as it is written in [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) you need to specify the `pad_width` for each axis.

> pad_width : .... unique pad widths for each axis....